# Eclipse IDE launched a new App Engine Standard instance when a new App Engine app was run

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have created multiple Google App Engine Standard Java projects with Eclipse neon.3 in my workspace. Google Cloud tool for Eclipse was installed properly. App Engine Standard Runtime was also added to Eclipse Server Run Environments properly.

My question is why a new "App Engine Standard at localhost" instance was launced when I ran a different project in my projects via Run As -> App Engine. For example, if I have 5 App Engine Standard Java projects in the Eclipse IDE, it needs to launch 5 App Engine Standard servers (one for each project obviously).

Is there a way for Eclipse to just launch one server instance for all my App Engine projects?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this **providing** that each of the projects has a different *Service ID*:

1. Select the different projects in your explorer and  right-click and choose *Run As > App Engine* (or *Debug As*). Note that this will reuse an existing definition if there is one with those projects already configured.
2. Edit an existing definition: From the *Servers* view, right-click on a server definition and choose *Add or Remove…* and add your projects to that definition.

You can also create a new server definition, either via *File > New > Server* or from the *Servers* view, and add your projects there.